# In a GPON network, running wireshark captures SIP phone calls from other users

Tags: networking, wireshark, isp, sip

I plugged my laptop into my ONT and fired up Wireshark.
To my surprise a lot of SIP packects were present, and I could see phone numbers of other costumers, and the people they called. I didn't capture any actual phone calls, with a stream to play.
Is this normal, should this be possible? It feels like it shouldn't.

My ONT has a single ethernet port. Behind that port are 3 VLANS, one for Data, another for Voice, and another for IPTV. I don't know from what VLAN the sip traffic came from, I assume the voice wan.
I connected my laptop to the ONT, and didn't do any extra configurations, just opened up Wireshark. This are the SIP packets I captured

sip packets - https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAeUr.jpg

sip flow - https://i.stack.imgur.com/yv5Bv.jpg

How, and why was I able to capture SIP packets from other customers. Is it expected in a GPON network?
I suspect if someone had made a call, I would be able to listen to it.
Obviously this is worrying, for privacy reasons.

EDIT: It is in fact possible to listen to the calls. But only one way, the downstream part. This is bad.

Comment: who is your internet provider - perhaps contact them with your concerns

Comment: @JaromandaX I am not sure how to contact my provider about this. There's only a phone support line, but they aren't trained to understand this, they aren't trained in networking, offer only basic support. Before I tried that, I would like to understand if this is normal.

Comment: I doubt it's *normal* - but then, an ISP here in Australia (Optus) made it easy for any of its customers to use any other customers SIP phone, both make and receive calls!!! That's why I asked which ISP, wondering if it's another Optus FAIL :p

Comment: @JaromandaX it's not australia. I am in Europe.  Thank you for sharing that, I can see why sip without tls would never be safe to use.